# Wordpress Search Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, search

I want to add a child-menu item titled Search. This would lead to a page that allows the person to search for items in specific categories or post types. For example if they click the search link off of the blog page it would send them to a page that searches only blog related categories (News, blog, etc.) and if they did so off of a video page they would search only video categories (episodes, documentaries, etc.)

Is there a native shortcode for the wordpress search function that I can add to a page that also has the ability to specify the categories to search in (only on the admin side) so the user doesn't know their search is being limited?

I would also like it to display the search results right below the search box so if they want to seach again they can.

Answer (score 0):

WP Search http://wpsear.ch/ has that ability.You can create pages with shortcode for custom search pages.